# Yammer API endpoint for Notes?

Tags: api, rest, yammer

I've been trying to figure out what the endpoint is for capturing 
and posting Yammer Notes but am not able to find it, does anyone 
know what it is? I had originally though it was [Notifications](https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-notifications)
but that doesn't seem to be it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no endpoint for notes. If you are a verified administrator you can use the [Data Export API](http://success.yammer.com/integrations/data-export/) to capture network data including notes, but you can't post or update them.

Comment: =( I wish I would have known about the data export feature before I wrote a application to do the exact same thing